# How can I delay a new tab from loading with a userscript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I use a userscript to modify the client-side code of a website. This code is adding an anchor tag to the page. Its target is `_blank`. The thing is that if I click this link too frequently, the site errors. A simple refresh on the new tab fixes the problem.

When I click on the link and it instantly opens a new tab. But I don't want that new tab to render until I visit it, or with some sort of time delay. Is there a way of achieving this?

I am using Firefox, so Firefox-only solutions are fine. [I found this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API), but I don't see a way of using it to prevent the tab from rendering in the first place. When I Google for this, I see results about add-ons that can solve the problem. But, the links to them always 404. Ideally, the solution would only affect the tabs created by this script instead of the way all tabs work, but if the only way to do it is to affect the way all tabs work, I'd accept that as a solution.

The [Tampermonkey documentation](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_openInTab) says there is a `GM_openInTab` function. It has a parameter called `loadInBackgroun`d, but it only decides if the new tab is focused when you click the link.

If there is a way of making this new tab render some HTML of my choosing, I think that would be a neat solution. i.e., I'd write some HTML that, on focus, goes to the actual website's page. If this is an option, I'd need to know how to open a tab to HTML of my choosing in grease monkey.

Comment: So in short you are looking for a way to open new background tab in "**snoozed**" (unloaded) state, right?  Sounds like interesting idea; I think full blown extensions with tab hiding capabilities could do something like that, but not GM alone.

Answer (score 1):

(Just realization of idea you told in your question yourself)

You can place simple page that waits for focus and then redirects to what you pass in URL parameter somewhere and open in background tabs. Like:

`load-url-from-search-on-focus.html?http://example.com`:

```
<!doctype html>
<body
 onload="document.title=u=location.search.slice(1)"
 onfocus="u?document.location.replace(u):document.write('?search missing')">
```

[Try it.](http://myfonj.github.io/tst/load-url-from-search-on-focus.html?http://example.org/)

---

(data:uri could have been used instead of hosted page, if there weren't those pesky security precautions blocking rendering of top-level datauri navigations :|)

Comment: I guess the one part I didn't think about on my own is how I could just have a github page do that for free. That could work. I prefer a way of doing it without setting up a separate site, but it's not a requirement

Comment: Sounds strange; so you see background tab title change to "Example Domain" even without focusing it?  Seems like either interesting browser bug firing focus event "prematurely" on page load or perhaps some other extension intervention? (Tried the test in current Firefoxes and Chromes and Edge and it worked as expected on My Machine™.)

Comment: No, actually my mistake: the title of that onload page confused me.  it's working as expected